# Plesk + PhpMyAdmin: Allow a user to see all their databases

Tags: phpmyadmin, plesk

Initially each user on a domain could access all their databases on phpmyadmin, but now when you click on the "phpmyadmin" button, it only shows the database you opened instead of all the databases that the user has access to.

For example, we have two users "xx" and "yy", and the following databases:

- xx_config
- xx_users
- yy_config
- yy_users

When you clicked, for example, on the "xx_config" phpmyadmin's button you would see and have access to all the "xx_" databases (which the user "xx" has access to), but now it only shows "xx_config".

This behavior started recently, I don't know if it was due to an update or something that I changed.

How do I change it so that the user's can access all their databases at same time, instead of one at a time?

Comment: indeed this quite strange feature become broken after update to 4.5.5

Comment: What do you mean by "It only shows the database you opened" -- is this some Plesk feature, or do you mean that in the navigation pane of phpMyAdmin once you click on a database the others are hidden from view? Sorry I'm not a Plesk user so I'm not sure yet if this is a Plesk problem or phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @ibennetch Basically, on Plesk there is a tab where you can see all the databases related to a user/domain. There a button beside each one to open PhpMyAdmin. Before when you pressed on that button, it would open PhpMyAdmin with all those databases listed on the navigation pane (left side), now it only shows the one that you clicked on.